# Return statement breaking my function c++

Tags: c++, arrays, return, return-value

So I call a function in main:
`B.remove()`

Which goes here
`m_arrays[m_oldest]->remove()`

Then finally here:

```
int MyClass::remove() {
    cout << "this is the remove function"<< endl;  //debugging line

    int lastVal = 0;

    for (int i = start; i < capacity; i++) {  //actual remove function
        if (m_array[i] != NULL) {
            int lastVal = m_array[i];
            m_array[i] = NULL;                  // sets to null
            m_size--;                           //increment
            break;
        }
    }
    m_start++;                                  //increment
    return lastVal;
}
```

If I remove the code containing lastVal, the function works properly. Why is this? Is there an easy way to fix this? 
As you can see I'm attempting to return a value before removing it from the array. I am aware I should be using vector or some other standard method, but I cannot.  I looked in my textbook but I couldn't find what I was looking for.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: please post an [mcve] so we can see everything your code is doing that is causing the problem.   The selection you have provided is likely not sufficient to point out to you the actual problem in your code

Comment: @xaxxon I didn't post a lot because its for a project and I didn't want to post my actual code to the internet. I was able to receive complete help though. Will try to be more complete in the future.

Comment: I think that was a mistake. Doubt OP wanted to show that two copies are useful

Comment: @xaxxon I can't delete it because there is an answer. They don't let you do that.

Comment: Yes I'm sorry it was a mistake.

Comment: @Cuber I misunderstood what "breaks my function" meant -- I was looking for a crash.   I'll delete this comment in a few minutes, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two `int lastVal` statements in your code - one before the `for` loop and one in it. Try removing the declaration inside the `for` loop (and set it to the assignment `lastVal = m_array[i];`) and see if it works.